# Proof that set $\{x \in\mathbb{R^n}: Ax+b\in C\}$ is convex, for $C\in\mathbb{R^m}$ and $A=m\times n$ matrix and $b\in\mathbb{R^m}$

Tags: analysis, convex-analysis

Proof that set $\{x \in\mathbb{R^n}: Ax+b\in C\}$ is convex, for $C\in\mathbb{R^m}$ is a convex set, $A=m\times n$ matrix and $b\in\mathbb{R^m}$

How do I make a start to proof this?

Comment: Easy to prove by definition: let $x_1$ and $x_2$ belong to the set and prove that the whole segment between them is in the set (using at some point convexity of $C$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Let $x, y \in \{x \in \Bbb R^n \mid Ax+b \in C\}$. You want to check that given $0 < t < 1$, you also have $tx+(1-t)y$ in that set. Meaning, you want to prove that $A(tx+(1-t)y)+b \in C$. But $A$ is linear and $C$ is convex, so? (You might want to write $b= tb + (1-t)b$, by the way)

Comment: So if i would call the set K. I need to show that for $x,y\in K$, $A(tx+(1−t)y)+b∈C$. And $C$ is convex so for $x,y\in C$, $tx+(1-t)x\in C$. When I write b the way you suggested, this is what I get: $t(Ay+b)+(1-t)(Ax+b)\in C$. But then I still havent proved it right? I am new to the proving techniques, so how to write something down is still hard.

Comment: All good. Just note that $t(Ay+b)+(1-t)(Ax+b) \in C$ because $Ax+b,Ay+b \in C$ and $C$ is convex. Since that expression is equal to $A(tx+(1-t)y)+b$, we get $tx+(1-t)y \in K$. Good job!